# Java statement in Genexus

Tags: java, genexus

I would like to use the following Java statement in GeneXus, but I don't know GeneXus' syntax for embedded Java code.

```
str = new String(str.getBytes("8859_1"), "UTF-8");
```

How can I do it?

Comment: FYI: if you think you need to do this, you probably have done something wrong before reaching this point and may already have data-loss (depending on how exactly you reached this point).

Answer (score 9):

```
&str = 'my text'

JAVA [!&str!] = new String([!&str!].getBytes("8859_1"), "UTF8");
```

[Documentation Link](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?Commands+to+include+source+code+in+GeneXus)

Comment: Hi, Gallotti..., I used and tested your java statement in my program of Genexus. But it has  java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException  error. What should I do? Please could you give me any advices?Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: UTF8 goes without "-"

Comment: Now , I understand why java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException error is appeared. It needs exception control. Thank you, Gonzalo.

Answer (score 1):

It needs Exception control as following.Without exception,java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException error will be appeared.

> &str = 'text'
>
> JAVA try { [!&str !] = new String([!&str !].getBytes("UTF-8")); } catch  (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) {  }

Answer (score 1):

Para incluir codigo java, necesitas usar la palabra reservada "java" al principio de cada linea. Si en esa linea necesitas acceder a una variable/atributo de GeneXus, o que esa variable sea accesible por GeneXus, necesitas rodear el nombre de la variable con [!...!]
Asi que tu codigo quedaria:

```
java try {
java [!&str!] = new String([!&str!].getBytes("8859_1"), "UTF-8");
java } catch (Exception ex) {
...
java }
```